# Laravel giving error "Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update"

Tags: laravel, azure, hosting

I am trying to host my application using Microsoft Azure. When I build my laravel web to Azure web app, the error I get is "Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update". I have run the command "composer update" but still get the same error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BeIN.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have the solution on your screenshot - enable php extension ext-fileinfo. How? Check [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-php?pivots=platform-windows#customize-phpini-settings)

Or, for just test deploy - add flag to install command

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: I have checked my php.ini file and run the command above, still get the same error.